# SSD interfering with fan speed control?

Tags: ssd, cooling

I have a new system, a MicroCenter Powerspec B819 with an Intel DP67DE board and i5 chip, and the fans run at full speed all the time.

I put in an SSD which is incorrectly reporting it's temp at 128C. I know nothings wrong with the drive, but I'm wondering if it's interfering with my ability to control the fan speed.

I've installed Intel Desktop Utilities, I've update my BIOS to BAP6710H.86A.0067.2011.0526.1448.
The Desktop Utilities program tells me that all temps are low - Processor 32, PCH 48, Memory 32, VR 29, other HD 30. It's just the SSD that is over threshold.

So is that drive keeping the fans from spinning down? Or is there a setting in BIOS I need to adjust to get them to adjust? This noise is driving me nuts!

Comment: Just an FYI, my solid state drive shows the exact same temperature... Does anyone know if that's the maximum temperature value for a sensor on the motherboard?

Comment: 128 is just a nice round number (at least in power of 2).  It is as likely to mean no reading or a false reading as are 0C and 100C/F/K/R/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Many SSDs don't have a temperature sensor in them, so they are not reporting a temperature at all. Many temperature monitoring programs blindly assume all drives report a temperature and when an SSD doesn't you can get all kinds of interesting and spectacular failures.

The best solution would be to update the temperature monitoring program to a version that fixes the problem, but it sounds like in your case there isn't such an update. Some SSD makers have released firmware updates which report a bogus temperature of 25C as a work around. You can see if anything like that is available for your SSD.